# org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Invalid request token'

Tags: java, twitter, scribe

can someone help me with this code? Everything goes great till this point.

```
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
```

After that I get this error.

> ERROR
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor-
>   Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this:
>   'Invalid request token' org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response
>   body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Invalid
>   request token'

I am new in Java and Scribes

```
import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class SignInTwitter extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4223895098942228518L;
private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json";

public String execute() {

    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(TwitterApi.class)
            .apiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .apiSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .callback("http://127.0.0.1:8080/SignInTwitter").build();

    // Obtain the Request Token

    Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

    String authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);

    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(authUrl);

    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,
            PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
    request.addBodyParameter("status", "this is sparta! *");
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    Response response = request.send();
    return "success";

}

}
```

Ok i added it to the code

```
ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor- Response             body        is  incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Invalid request token'
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Invalid request token'
at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:103)
at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:84)
at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:89)
at com.lingleonline.webclient.controllers.SignInTwitter.execute(SignInTwitter.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.lingleonline.webclient.controllers.CheckSession.intercept(CheckSession.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.lingleonline.webclient.controllers.MaintenanceCheck.intercept(MaintenanceCheck.java:74)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Post your stackTrace.

Answer (score 2):

you have to create the requestToken by the oauth_token and oauth_verifier in the redirected page like this :

http://www.example.com/xxxx?**oauth_token**=xxxxxx&**oauth_verifier**=xxxxxxx

```
try{
            OAuthService servicetwitter = twitterFacade.getService();
            Token requestToken = new Token(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("oauth_token"),FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("oauth_verifier"));
            String codes_twitter=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("oauth_verifier");
            System.out.println("code_twitter: "+codes_twitter);
            Verifier verifier_twitter = new Verifier(codes_twitter);
            Token accessToken_twitter = servicetwitter.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier_twitter);
            token_twitter=accessToken_twitter.getToken();
            System.out.println("token_twitter : "+token_twitter);
            loginbean.token=token_twitter;


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Had the exact same problem, this is the right solution. More info here: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/issues/560

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error due to two causes:

a) Due to wrong verifier

Check that you are setting proper verifier (probability very less if you are doing programmatically)

b) Incorrect scribe version

scribe-1.2.1 has some issue. Using scribe-1.3.1 solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your token and secret and valid. As I understand there is a validity time for either/both.

Answer (score 0):

> > See https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/issues/439

where it states that commenting the line

```
request.addBodyParameter("status", "this is sparta! *");
```

into

```
// request.addBodyParameter("status", "this is sparta! *");
```

Then it works.. It has something to do with text versus get data 
(no clue what that is)

> @schcriher Schmidt Cristian H.
>   I had the same problem and solve it by setting the status (text) to querystring (get data), as you mention. Thanks for the tip!
>
> > See https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11494